# Объект Date, скрипт «Время на учебу»

Tags: javascript, html

*Напишите скрипт «Время на учебу». На странице должны быть
предусмотрены кнопка и таблица размером 5на7, первая строка — названия дней недели,
первый столбец — время начала и конца пары. В ячейках таблицы должны быть
текстовые поля для ввода названия предмета, кнопка для подтверждения выбора.
Когда все расписание заполнено, клик по любой ее ячейке с названием предмета
должен показать количество часов и минут, которые по этому предмету отводятся на
его изучение. Клик правой клавишей мыши по телу документа подсчитывает общее
количество аудиторных часов и минут, которые должны быть потрачены на учебу.
Выводить информацию можно в окне alert.*

У меня получилось вот так:

```
<div class="tables">
    <h1 align="center" style="margin:40px;">Время на учебу</h1>
    <form action="#"onsubmit="submitForm()">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td align="center"><b>Дни недели</b></td>
            <td align="center"><b>Наименование пары</b></td>
            <td align="center"><b>Время начала </b></td>
            <td align="center"><b>Время конца</b></td>
        </tr>
            <tr>
            <td>Понедельник</td>
            <td><input type="text" id="parra" value required></td>
            <td><input type="time" class="timepar_a" required></td>
            <td><input type="time" class="timepar_b" required></td>
        </tr>
            <tr>
            <td>Вторник</td>
            <td><input type="text" id="parra" value required></td>
            <td><input type="time" class="timepar_a" required></td>
            <td><input type="time" class="timepar_b" required></td>
        </tr>
            <tr>
            <td>Среда</td>
            <td><input type="text" id="parra" value required></td>
            <td><input type="time" class="timepar_a" required></td>
            <td><input type="time" class="timepar_b" required></td>
        </tr>
            <tr>
            <td>Четверг</td>
            <td><input type="text" id="parra" value required></td>
            <td><input type="time" class="timepar_a" required></td>
            <td><input type="time" class="timepar_b" required></td>
        </tr>
                    <tr>
            <td>Пятница</td>
            <td><input type="text" id="parra" value required></td>
            <td><input type="time" class="timepar_a" required></td>
            <td><input type="time" class="timepar_b" required></td>
        </tr>
                <tr>
            <td>Субота</td>
            <td><input type="text" id="parra" value required></td>
            <td><input type="time" class="timepar_a" required></td>
            <td><input type="time" class="timepar_b" required></td>
        </tr>
        </table>
        <button class="numgo">Рассчитать</button>
        <div class="inf_parr"></div>
        </form>
<script type="text/javascript">
    let numgo = document.getElementsByClassName('numgo')[0];
    let parr = document.querySelectorAll("#parra");
    let par_l = parr.length;
    let parrt = document.querySelectorAll(".timepar");
    let par_t = parrt.length;
let timepar_a = document.querySelectorAll(".timepar_a");
let timepar_b = document.querySelectorAll(".timepar_b");
let inf_parr = document.querySelector(".inf_parr");

let s = 0;
for(s;s <= 5;s++){  parr[s].value = "Предмет " + s; }
// click========================================
numgo.onclick = function (){
let a0 = new Date("12 May, 2018 " + timepar_a[0].value + "");
let b0 = new Date("12 May, 2018 " + timepar_b[0].value + "");
let a1 = new Date("12 May, 2018 " + timepar_a[1].value + "");
let b1 = new Date("12 May, 2018 " + timepar_b[1].value + "");
let a2 = new Date("12 May, 2018 " + timepar_a[2].value + "");
let b2 = new Date("12 May, 2018 " + timepar_b[2].value + "");
let a3 = new Date("12 May, 2018 " + timepar_a[3].value + "");
let b3 = new Date("12 May, 2018 " + timepar_b[3].value + "");
let a4 = new Date("12 May, 2018 " + timepar_a[4].value + "");
let b4 = new Date("12 May, 2018 " + timepar_b[4].value + "");
let a5 = new Date("12 May, 2018 " + timepar_a[5].value + "");
let b5 = new Date("12 May, 2018 " + timepar_b[5].value + "");

let time0 = Math.abs(b0 - a0) / 3600000;
let time1 = Math.abs(b1 - a1) / 3600000;
let time2 = Math.abs(b2 - a2) / 3600000;
let time3 = Math.abs(b3 - a3) / 3600000;
let time4 = Math.abs(b4 - a4) / 3600000;
let time5 = Math.abs(b5 - a5) / 3600000;

let time = time0 + time1 + time2 + time3 + time4 + time5; 
 inf_parr.innerHTML = parr[0].value + ":" + time0 + "</br>" + 
                                            parr[1].value + ":" + time1 + "</br>" +
                                            parr[2].value + ":" + time2 + "</br>" + 
                                            parr[3].value + ":" + time3 + "</br>" + 
                                            parr[4].value + ":" + time4 + "</br>" + 
                                            parr[5].value + ":" + time5 + "</br>" +
                                            "allTime:" + time;
}
</script>
</div>
```

Это конечно похоже на правду, но всё-таки неправильно, помогите как сделать по заданию.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нашёл такое решение:

```html
<table class="table">
    <tr>
        <th>Время</th>
        <th>Понедельник</th>
        <th>Вторник</th>
        <th>Среда</th>
        <th>Четверг</th>
        <th>Пятница</th>
        <th>Суббота</th>            
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th>8:00-8:45</th>
        <td class="td">предмет: <input type="text" class="td__input"></td>            
        <td class="td">предмет: <input type="text" class="td__input"></td>            
        <td class="td">предмет: <input type="text" class="td__input"></td>            
        <td class="td">предмет: <input type="text" class="td__input"></td>            
        <td class="td">предмет: <input type="text" class="td__input"></td>            
        <td class="td">предмет: <input type="text" class="td__input"></td>            
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th>9:00-9:45</th>
        <td class="td">предмет: <input type="text" class="td__input"></td>            
        <td class="td">предмет: <input type="text" class="td__input"></td>            
        <td class="td">предмет: <input type="text" class="td__input"></td>            
        <td class="td">предмет: <input type="text" class="td__input"></td>            
        <td class="td">предмет: <input type="text" class="td__input"></td>            
        <td class="td">предмет: <input type="text" class="td__input"></td>      
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th>10:00-10:45</th>
        <td class="td">предмет: <input type="text" class="td__input"></td>            
        <td class="td">предмет: <input type="text" class="td__input"></td>            
        <td class="td">предмет: <input type="text" class="td__input"></td>            
        <td class="td">предмет: <input type="text" class="td__input"></td>            
        <td class="td">предмет: <input type="text" class="td__input"></td>            
        <td class="td">предмет: <input type="text" class="td__input"></td>     
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th>11:00-11:45</th>
        <td class="td">предмет: <input type="text" class="td__input"></td>            
        <td class="td">предмет: <input type="text" class="td__input"></td>            
        <td class="td">предмет: <input type="text" class="td__input"></td>            
        <td class="td">предмет: <input type="text" class="td__input"></td>            
        <td class="td">предмет: <input type="text" class="td__input"></td>            
        <td class="td">предмет: <input type="text" class="td__input"></td>      
    </tr>        
</table>

<button id="button">Применить</button>

<script>
    let button = document.getElementById('button');
let table = document.getElementsByClassName('table')[0];
let td = document.getElementsByClassName('td');
let tdInput = document.getElementsByClassName('td__input');

let math = 0;
let rusLanguage = 0;
let engLanguage = 0;
let PC = 0;
let chemistry = 0;
let biology = 0;
let history = 0;

button.onclick = btnComplete;

function btnComplete() {
for (let i = 0; i < td.length; i++) {
    td[i].innerHTML = tdInput[0].value;    
}

calcTime();

checkTime();

document.oncontextmenu = function() {
    let totalSum = math + rusLanguage + engLanguage + PC + chemistry + biology + history;

    alert(`${Math.floor(totalSum / 60)}ч : ${totalSum % 60}мин`)

    return false;
}
}

function calcTime() {
for (let i = 0; i < td.length; i++) {
    if (td[i].innerHTML == 'Математика') math += 45;
    if (td[i].innerHTML == 'Русский язык') rusLanguage += 45;
    if (td[i].innerHTML == 'Английский язык') engLanguage += 45;
    if (td[i].innerHTML == 'Физкультура') PC += 45;
    if (td[i].innerHTML == 'Химия') chemistry += 45;
    if (td[i].innerHTML == 'Биология') biology += 45;
    if (td[i].innerHTML == 'История') history += 45;
}
}

function checkTime() {
table.onclick = function(event) {
    let cell = event.target;

    if (cell.tagName != 'TD') return;

    if (cell.innerHTML == 'Математика') {
        if (math == 45) alert('0ч : 45мин');
        if (math > 45) alert(`${Math.floor(math / 60)}ч : ${math % 60}мин`);
    }
    if (cell.innerHTML == 'Русский язык') {
        if (rusLanguage == 45) alert('0ч : 45мин');
        if (rusLanguage > 45) alert(`${Math.floor(rusLanguage / 60)}ч : ${rusLanguage % 60}мин`);
    }
    if (cell.innerHTML == 'Английский язык') {
        if (engLanguage == 45) alert('0ч : 45мин');
        if (engLanguage > 45) alert(`${Math.floor(engLanguage / 60)}ч : ${engLanguage % 60}мин`);
    } 
    if (cell.innerHTML == 'Физкультура') {
        if (PC == 45) alert('0ч : 45мин');
        if (PC > 45) alert(`${Math.floor(PC / 60)}ч : ${PC % 60}мин`);
    }
    if (cell.innerHTML == 'Химия') {
        if (chemistry == 45) alert('0ч : 45мин');
        if (chemistry > 45) alert(`${Math.floor(chemistry / 60)}ч : ${chemistry % 60}мин`);
    }
    if (cell.innerHTML == 'Биология') {
        if (biology == 45) alert('0ч : 45мин');
        if (biology > 45) alert(`${Math.floor(biology / 60)}ч : ${biology % 60}мин`);
    }
    if (cell.innerHTML == 'История') {
        if (history == 45) alert('0ч : 45мин');
        if (history > 45) alert(`${Math.floor(history / 60)}ч : ${history % 60}мин`);
    }
}
}
</script>
```

Comment: В текущем виде ваш ответ непонятен. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] под сообщением, чтобы добавить больше подробностей, которые помогут другим понять, как он отвечает на заданный вопрос. Вы можете найти больше информации о том, как писать хорошие ответы в [Справке](/help/how-to-answer).